# Present simple/present continuous + when clause

Tags: meaning

How do the meanings change if they change?

> 1 I am always thinking of Jacky when I see a fat vender.
>
> 2 I always think of Jacky when I see a fat vender.

--

> 3 He is taking a shower when the water goes off.
>
> 4 He takes a shower when the water goes off.

Answer (score 3):

There's an important difference between continuous and simple tenses when using "when" as a conjunction.

(In my answer here, I'm going to talk about the "main clause" and the "when-clause". To be clear, the "when clause" is the one that starts with "when", and the other one is the "main clause".)

If the main clause is not continuous, then the when-clause happens first and causes the main clause to happen.

> I answered the phone when it rang. (*first it rings, then that causes me to answer it*)
> When I stand in front of an audience, I shiver. (*I get in front of the audience, and that causes me to shiver*)

If the main clause is continuous, then it means the main clause started happening before the when-clause. There's no nuance that one causes the other.

> I was having breakfast when the phone rang. (*first I start eating breakfast, then the phone rings*)
> When you call, I'm often working. (*first I start working, then you call*)

Now to your example sentences.

Sentence 1 means I often have Jacky in my mind before I see a fat vendor. That's pretty odd.

Sentence 2 means seeing a fat vendor reminds me of Jacky, whom I'm assuming is a fat vendor, so this makes sense.

Sentence 3 means the water goes off regularly, and he's usually in the shower when that happens.

Sentence 4 means when the water goes off, it makes him take a shower, which is probably impossible since there's no water.

Answer (score 2):

(2) and (3) are the correct versions.

(1) sounds as though you are already thinking about Jacky every time you see a fat 'vender' (do you mean *vendor* - someone selling something?).

(4) sounds as though he tries to take a shower *because* the water has gone off!

Comment: Which action takes place first in 3: taking a shower or water's going off? I think the shower taking. Right?

Comment: @user1425 - logically, he can't take a shower when the water goes off.

Comment: Yes, of course - and that's why you have to say "He is [already] taking a shower..."